# setTimeout not working with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html

First, here are the problematic lines of code:

```
<a onmouseover="hoverDisplay(this)" onmouseout="setTimeout(unHoverDisplay(), 3000);" href="http://rabbit.jpg">
            Rabbit
        </a><br>
```

Basically, I want the image to load and appear when I hover over the link, and I want the it to disappear **after some time** when I hover out of the link. The methods:

```
hoverDisplay(this)
unHoverDisplay()
```

display and remove the image, respectively, but when I tried to delay unHoverDisplay(), it didn't work; the image disappeared the moment my mouse hovered off the link.

I've tried adding and removing the semicolon after the setTimeout (not sure if the semicolon is necessary or not), and I tried delaying the hoverDisplay function as well, which did not work. Aside from the delay problem, the two functions work as intended.

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Not sure if this is necessary, but here are the implementations of the two functions:

```
//Display image for link that you hover over
            var address; //Address of image
            var toBeDisplayed; //Declaring img object
            var maxHeight=screen.height;
            var maxWidth=screen.width;
            var invisible=document.getElementById("invisible"); //the div in which the image is contained

            function hoverDisplay(imageLink)
            {
                address=imageLink.getAttribute("href"); //get address

                toBeDisplayed=document.createElement("img"); //create img                           
                toBeDisplayed.setAttribute("src", address); //give img the address

                //Resize img if it doesnt fit on the screen
                if(toBeDisplayed.height > maxHeight)
                {
                    toBeDisplayed.style.height="" + maxHeight + "px";
                }
                else if(toBeDisplayed.width > maxWidth)
                {
                    toBeDisplayed.style.width="" + maxWidth + "px";
                }

                invisible.appendChild(toBeDisplayed); //display image by adding it as a child to a div
                invisible.style.visibility="visible"; //make div visible
                toBeDisplayed.style.border="solid yellow 5px";

            }
            //Remove image once you hover out of the link
            function unHoverDisplay()
            {
                //Removes all children of the div
                while(invisible.firstChild)
                {
                    invisible.removeChild(invisible.firstChild); //remove img by removing it as a child
                }
                invisible.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that the parentheses after unHoverDisplay in your first argument to `setTimeout` are causing unHoverDisplay to be executed immediately. You simply want to pass the function by its identifier without the parentheses:

```
onmouseout="setTimeout(unHoverDisplay, 3000);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a function as a parameter to setTimeout, not invoking it. Hence, you don't need those parentheses along with the function name, all that is required is the function name itself.

onmouseout = "setTimeout(unHoverDisplay, 3000);"